# Runtime memory Haskell

Tags: haskell, memory, runtime

I was trying to write a program in Haskell and I wanted to write a function which when called gives me the free memory and the total memory at that instance. I know that in Java I can write something like `runtime.getruntime().totalmemory()` inside a method. I am fairly new to Haskell and can't figure out how to hard code something like this inside my program.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [getGCStats](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/GHC-Stats.html#v:getGCStats) function in `GHC.Stats` to get the amount of memory used as of the last GC (`currentBytesUsed`).

You might have to compile your program with `-rtsopts` and run it with `+RTS -T` to enable the stats.

Answer (score 1):

Apparantly the API changed a bit in newer GHC's. The following checks first if you've used `+RTS -T` and then (based on https://ofb.net/~elaforge/karya/hscolour/Util/Memory.html ) uses the correct API based on GHC_VERSION:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE CPP #-}

import           GHC.Int    (Int64)
import qualified GHC.Stats

rtsMemUsage :: IO (Maybe Int64)
rtsMemUsage = do
  enabled <- GHC.Stats.getGCStatsEnabled
  if enabled
  then
#if GHC_VERSION >= 80401
    Just . GHC.Stats.gcdetails_mem_in_use_bytes . GHC.Stats.gc <$> GHC.Stats.getRTSStats
#else
    Just . GHC.Stats.currentBytesUsed <$> GHC.Stats.getGCStats
#endif
  else return Nothing
```